# skipping a character in an array if previous character is the same

Tags: c++, switch-statement, cstring

I'm iterating through an array of `chars` to do some manipulation. I want to "skip" an iteration if there are two adjacent characters that are the same.

e.g. x112abbca
skip----------^

I have some code but it's not elegant and was wondering if anyone can think of a better way? I have a few `case`'s in the `switch` statement and would be happy if I didn't have to use an `if` statement inside the `switch`.

```
switch(ent->d_name[i])
{
            if(i > 0 && ent->d_name[i] == ent->d_name[i-1])
                continue;
            case ' ' :
            ...//code omited
            case '-' :
            ...
}
```

By the way, an instructor once told me "avoid `continue`s unless much code is required to replace them". Does anyone second that? (Actually he said the same about `break`s)

Comment: `continue` is just fine here, IMO. What did your instructor suggest to use instead? Note also that you're comparing `ent->d_name[i-1]` to itself.

Comment: Structured-programming zealots dislike `continue` and `break` for similar reasons that they abhor `goto`: they introduce what they consider unnecessary complexity into the flow of control.  Like most programming ideologies, there's some truth to this view, but these constructs can also simplify code and make it easier to read as well.  Take it on a case-by-case basis, like pretty much everything else.

Comment: `break`s are unavoidable in some, if not many, instances(IMHO), especially in `switch` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `if` outside the `switch`.

While I don't have anything against using `continue` and `break`, you can certainly bypass them this time without *much* code at all: simply revert the condition and put the whole switch statement within the if-block.

Answering the rectified question: what's clean depends on many factors. How long is this list of characters to consider: should you iterate over them yourself, or perhaps use a utility function from `<algorithm>`? In any case, if you are referring to the same character multiple times, perhaps you ought to give it an alias:

```
std::string interesting_chars("-_;,.abc");

// ...
for (i...) {
  char cur = abc->def[i];
  if (cur != prev || interesting_chars.find(cur) == std::string::npos)
      switch (current) // ...
```

Comment: @Celeritas, I don't know what to make of your edit. Certainly I don't know what you think the original code manages to do, but putting `if` inside a switch like that is useless: it's dead code.

Answer (score 0):

```
char chr = '\0';
char *cur = &ent->d_name[0];
while (*cur != '\0') {
    if (chr != *cur) {
        switch(...) {
        }
    }
    chr = *cur++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can clobber the content of the array you are analyzing, you can preprocess it with `std::unique()`:

```
ent->erase(std::unique(ent->d_name.begin(), ent->d_name.end()), ent.end());
```

This should replace all sequences of identical characters by a single copy and shorten the string appropriately. If you can't clobber the string itself, you can create a copy with character sequences of just one string:

```
std::string tmp;
std::unique_copy(ent->d_name.begin(), ent->d_name.end(), std::back_inserter(tmp));
```

In case you are using C-strings: use `std::string` instead. If you insist in using C-strings and don't want to play with `std::unique()` a nicer approach than yours is to use a `previous` character, initialized to `0` (this can't be part of a C-string, after all):

```
char previous(0);
for (size_t i(0); ent->d_name[i]; ++i) {
    if (ent->d_name[i] != previous) {
        switch (previous = ent->d_name[i]) {
             ...
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Something I don't get about C++ is it seems many functions and objects use cstrings instead of strings. According to the [docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirent.h.html) `d_name` is an array of chars, so I don't know if `.begin` and `.end()` will work?

Comment: If `d_name` is an array, you won't have `begin()` and `end()` members. However, you could, e.g. use `ent->d_name + strlen(ent->d_name)` to get an end iterator. You also can't use `erase()` on an array, so you would capture the end, e.g., with `char const* end = std::unique(ent->d_name, ent->d_name + strlen(ent->d_name));`.

Comment: So I guess I'll try you last example. Are you sure the for loop works correctly? How is `ent->d_name[i]` make a condition?

Comment: @Celeritas, `<dirent.h>` specifies a C API, thus the use of "C strings".

Comment: @Celeritas: `ent->d_name[i]` is either the null character, i.e., the end of the string, where the loop should terminate or it is a non-null character and the loop should continue. Null converts to `false`, everything else to `true`. Basically, `ent->d_name[i]` is equivalent to `ent->d_name[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: I didn't know null converts to false in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you are trying to do, anyway this will find matching pairs and skip over a match.

```
char c_anotherValue[] = "Hello World!";

int i_len = strlen(c_anotherValue);
for(int i = 0; i < i_len-1;i++)
{
    if(c_anotherValue[i] == c_anotherValue[i+1])
    {
        printf("%c%c",c_anotherValue[i],c_anotherValue[i+1]);
        i++;//this will force the loop to skip
    }
}
```